# Android: template pattern with fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, design-patterns, data-binding

This should be an easy question, but for some reason I am having trouble with it. Let's say I have a FragmentOne and FragmentTwo. FragmentOne looks like this:

```
private static final String PATH_KEY = "path_key";

private Asset asset;

public FragmentOne() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


public static FragmentOne newInstance(Asset asset) {
    FragmentOne fragment = new FragmentOne();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable(PATH_KEY, asset);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        asset = (Asset) getArguments().getSerializable(PATH_KEY);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
        final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final FragmentOneBinding binding = DataBindingUtil
            .inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_video, container, false);
    bindAsset(binding, asset);
    return binding.getRoot();
}

public void bindAsset(FragmentOneBinding binding, Asset asset) {
    binding.textView.setText("FragOne displays asset like this " + asset.text);
    //this is the only method which differs from FragmentTwo

}
```

while FragmentTwo looks like this:

```
private static final String PATH_KEY = "path_key";

private Asset asset;

public FragmentTwo() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


public static FragmentTwo newInstance(Asset asset) {
    FragmentTwo fragment = new FragmentTwo();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable(PATH_KEY, asset);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        asset = (Asset) getArguments().getSerializable(PATH_KEY);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
        final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final FragmentTwoBinding binding = DataBindingUtil
            .inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_video, container, false);
    bindAsset(binding, asset);
    return binding.getRoot();
}

public void bindAsset(FragmentOneBinding binding, Asset asset) {
    binding.textView.setText("But FragTwo, which is very different, displays asset like this " + asset.image.getName());
    //this is the only method which differs from FragmentOne

}
```

As you can see, in both fragments, the newInstance, onCreate, and onCreateView methods are structurally the same. The only real difference is that the bindView method called from inside the onCreateView of both fragments is not the same.

Using generics, abstract classes, interfaces, or some combination, can I simplify things down to a template design pattern? So that the next time I want to make a fragment with the exact same structure I can do something a little like this?

```
class FragmentThree extends TemplateFragment {

    @Override
    public void bindAsset(FragmentThreeBinding binding, Asset asset){
        binding.textView.setText(asset.name);
    }

}
```

I tried making an abstract class already, but you can't have a static method in an abstract class, so newInstance() stops me here. I've tried a few ways of implementing interfaces as well, but am not having any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the abstract class you attempted is the right way to go. You will need to still put `newInstance()` in each concrete subclass, not only because it is static, but also because it needs to know the concrete type to instantiate.

Comment: Hi there. You are right, and taking your approach does simplify the code somewhat, though not as much as I had hoped. I will accept your answer. If I need to factor out the newInstance part as well, though, what do you recommend? Some kind of factory class? (in my case FragmentOne, FragmentTwo, and Fragment Three are all instantiated in different FragmentSwitcher classes which are all ALSO functionally the same except for the type of fragment to switch to. It would be nice to reduce these to a single generic switcher class).

Comment: Does this FragmentSwitcher class create multiple instances of the same fragment class or can it function with a single instance?

Comment: @ike Ideally you should post a new question with a link to this one.

Answer (score -1):

abstract method cann't  use static 。
Factory Mode in order to create class instantiate.
Fragment use Factory Mode ,itself add static Method .